# BigQuery - changing order of fields in schema

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an existing table that has two subelements that contain the same data, but the fields in the elements are defined in a different order.

Below is an example of the schema (the real schema is much more complicated, and contains multiple levels of nested and repeated fields)

```
+- record2: record             
|  +- list: record (repeated)    
|  |  |- field1: integer         
|  |  |- field2: integer         
+- record: record                
|  +- list: record (repeated)    
|  |  |- field2: integer         
|  |  |- field1: integer
```

I'm trying to run the following query and fail ("No matching signature for function COALESCE..."):

```
select
  field1,
  field2
  from `dataset.table` 
  left join unnest([coalesce(record2,record)]) as elem
```

Is there a way to change the order of fields in an existing schema?

Is there a way to add a new field to a RECORD element and set the element not to be appended last? I tried using UPDATE table, but it seems the API forces the field to be added as the last element in the RECORD.

Comment: can you clarify your real use case?

Comment: I have a table that is generated automatically, where a certain subelement has moved (over time) from one location to another, with small schema changes. I'm trying to leave all queries in place by using a query of this sort (elements are part of list, so I already had to use unnest in the past): 
select
  ... from `table`
  left join unnest([coalesce(oldElement,newElement)]) as element
I now need a way to change the existing schema of "oldElement" and "newElement" to match, but it seems I cannot change the order of fields in an existing schema

Comment: But query DOES NOT have dependency on order of fields! can you share what exactly problem you experiencing that leads you think you need to control the order. or I still missing something. I think you should update your question with more details/specifics, so you have better chances to get help

Comment: Coalesce or Union do require all elements to have the same schema (including order of fields).

Comment: That's true. As changing columns is probably not an option - try to look into your problem from different angle - like eliminate use of COALESCE. of course with UNION there will be more troubles - but there is almost always workaround. I will check if I can propose something to address COALESCE aspect of this when have time :o)